# Photos needed for the site design.

Tags: discussion, design, featured-photo

Hi all. I'm currently in the process of wrapping up the [design concept](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378/design-for-photography-site) for the final theme when the Photography site graduates from Beta.

I need your best photos for part of the design mockup. landscape orientation please. I'll scale it down to 375x210 px, so please make sure it'd scale well, crop if needed.

Please upload or post url to photo in answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Ohh, so many to choose from! These are a couple of my favourites:

[Morning of Dec. 22](http://www.flickr.com/photos/grantpalin/3129637566/in/set-72157611466379483/)

[image: A December morning]

[Springtime at Royal Roads](http://www.flickr.com/photos/grantpalin/3503217476/in/set-72157617113828465/)

[image: Springtime at Royal Roads]

Comment: First one is awesome - I think it would look well in the design Jin has posted in a separate thread.

Comment: "Morning of Dec.22" is beautiful, @Grant!

Comment: Agreed, "Morning of" is excellent. :)

Comment: The "Morning of" photo is prominently featured on the homepage of the main site - *awesome!*

Answer (score 5):

Longs Peak:
[image]

Thunderglow:
[image]

Stormy Sunset:
[image]

Comment: Love Stormy Sunset.

Comment: Longs Peak is gorgeous!

Comment: ...and I like Thunderglow :)

Comment: Thanks guys. :) Thunderglow was a lucky catch right at the last rays of sunset. One of my favorites. Longs Peak is pretty gorgeous in the super early AM. ;)

Comment: Wow, these pictures are so much brighter on my work screen! There is such a massive difference between a calibrated screen and a non-calibrated screen....scary.

Comment: All very nice! I'm leaning towards thunderglow as the best among these.

Answer (score 4):

I'll join in with Rowland with a couple for now:

"Sorrow" from the Capitoline Museum in Rome

[image: Sorrow]

"Delicate" from my backyard...

[image: Delicate]

"Nature's Tears" from my garden

[image: Nature's Tears]

Comment: Nice photos. I'm a sucker for dandelion photos.

Comment: Thanks Jin! Hopefully we'll see some more from the other regulars soon.

Comment: Wow, the dandelion is amazing!

Comment: For your macro work, what gear do you use?

Comment: @Jarrod: Thanks! I have a Vivitar f/2.8 100mm macro and a Sigma 70-300mm macro lens. The Vivitar is a classic lens made by Kiron (Vivitar designed them), considered to be one of the best macro lenses ever made. However, it is fully manual, all metal, and heavy. Fun to use though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start the ball rolling; How about "No Fishin":

[image: No Fishin]

Or "Fluffy":

[image: Fluffy]

Comment: thanks for the submission.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we'll find better out there

Comment: Awesome, especially the name "Fluffy!"

Comment: Hood looks mounted incorrectly on 'Fluffy'... Guess you can correct in post if you really like it and you disclose that its a photo manipulation.

Comment: @Itai The vignette is intentional; In this case helped along with a polariser...

Answer (score 1):

Autumn Pine:
[image]

Walking Bridge:
[image]

Comment: I really love the pine cones! That has such a perfect autumn feel to it.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have been using that (sized correctly of course) as the desktop at work this fall